# Android - SQLite Database with Object Models

Tags: android, sqlite, object, android-contentprovider, dao

I am creating an Application in Android that uses a SQLite database. So far i have 3 table, one of which is used to link the first two tables together with foreign keys.

I have been reading a lot online about CursorLoaders, Content Providers, AsyncTask, URI's.... etc. A content provider seems like over-kill for my application, I do not intend to share this SQLite data with other applications.

My question: Is it a good idea in Android to create an object model of each row of Data from the database? My application wouldn't realistically have more than 500 objects from these databases, but is this good design/approach?

More Details: If I were to go down the Object route, I would use these objects and map them to Listviews mostly. Some of these objects may contain arraylists of other objects, Say for instance mapping these kinds of objects to expandable listviews. I tried this approach and it worked really well, I am just unsure of making all of these objects is wasting resources, slowing things down, or will it become a problem later if I decide to expand the application? What if i had 5000 Objects? Just unsure if it's a valid programming approach.

Comment: That depends on what you want to do... you should give more details.

Comment: Maybe reading about CursorAdapter will help you here.

Comment: I don't think this question really has an answer: So much depends on what you are going to do and what you are comfortable with.  My opinion, FWIW, after doing this a lot, on the Android platform, is that you should avoid object models if you can.  Just use Cursors and ContentValues wherever possible.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I am leaning towards your suggestion about avoiding the object models, it does seem to be a waste of resources, especially on a mobile platform for the sake of convenience.